# Convert vcproject to makefile for nix?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, makefile

So I have a visual studio 2008 project setup for a project I've been working on however its a sub project of a rather larger code base which is crossplatform, so in order to make my project complaint with the main source I need to make my project nix compilable.

Is there some way I can generate a makefile based off my vcproject? or if not is there someway I could generate a makefile any other way than writing it manually as it appears confusing as all hell when I open them up.

Comment: Make is a technology that's about as outdated as assembly. Consider moving to another portable build system. If you need compatibility with older makefiles, consider a build system that works by creating makefiles.

Comment: That probably doesn't answer the question, but you might take a look at SCons, a cross-platform building tool. I use it for my projects that needs to compile on both Windows (using Visual Studio) and UNIX (using gcc)

Comment: At work we do the reverse. Our repository contains a bunch of Qt .pro files, and each time we add files etc. we modify the .pro's and regenerate a solution from that. We convert them to any version of Visual Studio and MingW/G++ Makefiles.

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/870533/1106459

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has dropped the support for exporting a solution into a makefile (see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/ad896ca7-39db-4d90-b130-19f54ceed784)). I'm not aware of any external tools that convert VS solutions to makefiles.
But i had some success using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). With CMake you describe a project in a textfile and cmake then generates standard makefiles or project descriptions for IDE's (including VS).

Answer (score 0):

[Nobody ever writes a Makefile. They take an existing Makefile and modify it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556532/how-often-will-a-programmer-be-asked-to-write-a-makefile-file)

Get one of the makefiles from the existing projects and adjust it to your project (i.e. replace project name, source/object files, etc).

Other than that, simple makefiles are not so difficult, [here's a very short introduction to makefiles](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) to get you started.

Comment: This is more or less along the lines of what I'm currently doing, however my project is a .DLL under the windows environment and needs to be generated into its nix counterpart .so I believe, whilst the rest of the project is a executable.